# What are the mechanics behind Win10's OneDrive?

Tags: windows-10, sync, onedrive

Lets say I have two different Win10 computers with OneDrive and I share some images through an Outlook account. What exactly does OneDrive do in the technical sense?

1. Does it simply create a "shared folder" as in, if I change something on the first computer, it will also change in the other computer/all devices with OneDrive?
2. Does it simply push new content into the drive from PC1 and just download what PC2 doesn't have?
3. Some other variant of sync shenigans?

Comment: What's the difference between #1 and #2 (and #3), anyway?

Comment: Number 2 would not delete any files and number 3 is just for any other mechanic I might've missed.

Comment: OneDrive syncs your local files in the OneDrive folder with the files located in the cloud.  If either of these sources change the other is updated (provided you are logged into the client).  Since OneDrive on Windows 10 does not have offline placeholders (yet) thats the best description I can provide.

Answer (score 0):

OneDrive, Google Drive, DropBox or any other similar service will keep the content of its folder the same on all connected devices where you select a certain folder to be synced.

OneDrive does not actually have an option to only partially share content, it will delete a file from all pc's if you delete it at some area. Of course, the files are not permanently deleted yet as they remain restorable for a certain time through the OneDrive website. Like an Undo.